# Python module runs but a function wont

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, network-programming, streaming

although I know Python syntaxis and wrote some scripts for data processing and analysis (spectra and images) which do the job, I've never really worked with networking or streaming and guess I must admit that my programming skills are pretty low. Perhaps, I'm trying to handle more than my current skills allow, but that's probably a common situation for development.

Anyways, I'm working on (yet another) gui-client to control Raspberry Pi camera - both for fun and for the sake of learning. To cut a long story short, I would like to run a streaming http server from this gui. I went for a ready solution and followed this recipe

http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
description of webpage
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

OK, so this code works fine if it is run as a standalone application. But if I instead try to have it run as a function, i.e. if I want to do smth like this after the classes construction

```
def main():
    with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
            output = StreamingOutput()
            camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
            try:
                address = ('', 8000)
                server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
                server.serve_forever()
            except(KeyboardInterrupt):
                camera.stop_recording()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

then it won't stream, although the output and server objects are created. I am really puzzled, could anyone, please, answer why? - I would not be surprised if the answer turns out to be simple and the question is stupid, and therefore would be grateful if someone could recommend some tutorials or simplistic reading on writing a server/client for streaming/receiving the data.

Another thing is that I'd like to be able to kill this server upon request - for this, I guess the good solution is to use threading module and have the gui and the server running in separate threads?
Many thanks

N

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the first answer is pretty straightforward.

The problem is that the variable `output` which you try to read in `StreamingHandler` is not in **scope** when your code that defines it is inside a function called `main`.

```
output = 5

def test():
    print(output)

# the following statement runs fine, output is in scope because it
# was defined in the top-level scope   
test()

def test_2():
    print(output_2)

def main():
    output_2 = 6
    test_2()

# error! test_2 doesn't know the value of output_2 because the
# output_2 variable was declared within main()
main()
```

So, you need to work out a way to pass the `output` variable to the server. My approach is to declare output as a class variable in `StreamingHandler`, and add `output` as an argument when instantiating a new `StreamingServer` as follows:

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
description of webpage
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    output = None

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with StreamingHandler.output.condition:
                        StreamingHandler.output.condition.wait()
                        frame = StreamingHandler.output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True
    def __init__(self, address, handler, output):
        handler.output = output
        super().__init__(address, handler)

def main():
    with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
            output = StreamingOutput()
            camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
            try:
                address = ('', 8000)
                server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler, output)
                server.serve_forever()
            except(KeyboardInterrupt):
                camera.stop_recording()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I leave your question about killing the server to my learned colleages for now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. Indeed, it worked as described, and the explanation was quite clear, although I'm still a bit confused with class variables.

Comment: Sure, that part was a bit tricky if you are new to object oriented programming. This article gives quite a nice introduction into the different types of variables in classes and objects: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3